# .click() event operating on <span>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I want to trigger a click event on a span but it's not working. I tried both of the following:

```
$('#my_span').click();
$('#my_span').trigger("click");
```

But then I tried:

```
$('#my_span').focus();
```

And this worked! Anybody know why? I am not trying to bind a handler, just trying to trigger the click event like an user clicking on that span. Please help.

Comment: What does clicking on a span suppose to do if there is no handler on it?

Comment: If you're trying to focus the span, then `focus` would be the correct event to trigger. Generally, clicking a span doesn't do anything, as it's not really a clickable element, unless there's some javascript involved.

Answer (score 0):

Try triggering `click` on the DOM element instead of on the jQuery collection of the element:

```
$('#my_span')[0].click();
```

Or:

```
document.getElementById('my_span').click();
```

Comment: That should make no difference as jQuery does all that behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Does your span hold any information? Is is a 0px by 0px element? If that's the case the click will never be triggered.

For instance, if you look at a font-awesome icon inside a `<span>` or `<i>` it will never be triggered since it has nothing to click.

Answer (score -1):

//EDITED BECAUSE I CANT READ PROPERLY ^^//

I would chain up two event handlers

```
$(document).on("event you desire","desired target", function() {  
        $("#my_span").trigger("click");
    });
```

then:

```
$(document).on("click","#my_span", function() {  
    //stuff to happen
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vvt8Lvvu/ - jsfiddle for demo

Comment: While *delegated event handlers* can be a good thing, *there is no event handler involved in this question*... He is trying to generate a click on the element.

Comment: yeah i didnt read properly, but i just have the feeling that its part of the problem ^^

Comment: You have a feeling delegated event handlers will solve an issue with triggering an event programatically ?

Comment: This still has *nothing to do with the question* as **they they are not trying to handle the click, just focus the element**. This would only be a solution if their element was added dynamically, which is obviously not the case as `.focus()` works :)

Comment: Why are you saying "I would chain up *two* event handlers" when you only have one and no chaining? This answer is making me dizzy now :)

Comment: from what we know, and that is 3 lines of code, obviously triggering a click handler does not work, so what exactly is wrong by showing him "hey just chain up two handlers, see this works here"? maybe the element he tries to "click" is not present in the dom and cant be correctly given an event handler?

Comment: Please read the question again. Specifically: "But then I tried:`$('#my_span').focus();` And this worked!`"... That means that the element *is* present. Your new explanation "just chain up two handlers" makes no sense as it does not match your code. You are not chaining up two event handlers. You are registering a single delegated event handler on a non-changing ancestor element. :(

Comment: it is present the moment he tries to focus yes - as said, from the explanation given, we can only guess whats happening - and my guess is that the element to be clicked is not yet there when he maybe tries to attach the click handler, which will do stuff later - hence delegate it;